# How to use kCIInputTransformKey on iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-image, cgaffinetransform

I'm creating a `CIFilter` for a `AVMutableVideoComposition`

Since it doesn't support both a filter and layer instructions, I tried to apply the transform I need directly in the filter:

```
    filter.setValue(transform, forKey: kCIInputTransformKey)
```

Where `transform` is a `CGAffineTransform`

This throws the exception

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key inputTransform.'

Now the doc says

> A key for an NSAffineTransform object that specifies a transformation
>   to apply.

But `NSAffineTransform` does not exist on iOS.

How to use `CGAffineTransform` or iOS, or what substitute could replace it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to apply directly the transform in the filter.

This can be done by applying it to the source image.

```
request.sourceImage.transformed(by: transform)
```

edit: As Frank pointed out; not all filters support transforms!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the transform in an `NSValue`:

```
filter.setValue(NSValue(cgAffineTransform: transform), forKey: kCIInputTransformKey)
```

Comment: It still generate an exception for me

Comment: What filter are you using? It seems the filter doesn't have an input transform property.

Comment: let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISourceOverCompositing")!

Comment: Yes, this only has two parameters for the input and the background. See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISourceOverCompositing

Comment: I understand now ! Thank you :)